# Verify that Decimal Value is in YYYY.Q format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a SQL Server FLOAT column that is supposed to represent a future quarter:

Delivery_Date (float, null)

Though this is not an ideal format for date representation, I receive the data in an Excel workbook and have an SSIS package to load it into SQL Server. It comes from an outside vendor, so it is what it is.

Values must be in YYYY.Q format.  The Year Quarter needs to be in the future, so, if we’re in Q3 2016, a value of 2016.3 is incorrect. Values that have just the year, and no quarter, are also incorrect.

What is the best way to formulate this check?

Comment: I hope this is not homework, as otherwise your prof would be a really cruel monster. Why not storing Q3 2016 as 2016/07/01?

Answer (score 2):

A `float` is a really, really, really, really, really bad way to express this data, because float is an *approximate* representation of decimal numbers.  To the extent that you have any control over the structure you should change it to `decimal(5, 1)`, or some other type.

You can get the current quarter in this form using:

```
select year(getdate()) + datepart(quarter, getdate()) / 10.0
```

The problem is that small rounding difference might mean that the following does not work as expected:

```
where Delivery_Date <= year(getdate()) + datepart(quarter, getdate()) / 10.0
```

The delivery date might be 2016.30000000001 and the second part might return 2016.299999997.  They both *look* like "2016.3", but they are not equal.

I suppose you can add a little delta to make it work:

```
where Delivery_Date <= 0.01 + year(getdate()) + datepart(quarter, getdate()) / 10.0
```

But using `float` inappropriate is dangerous.

Comment: I agree that the decimal is better than a float, but it would be better still to have separate columns for query performance.  I hate parsing data in my queries =/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the column type.

Comment: Your 2016.3 may be stored as 2016.299999999 in a `float` column. What are you going to do then?

Comment: I receive the data in an Excel workbook and have an SSIS package to load it into SQL Server.  It comes from an outside vendor, so it is what it is